# pyinstaller Warnings - lib not found: python39.dll

Tags: python, dll, pyinstaller

I've been trying to create an exe of a simple script using pyinstaller, but when I use it I get the following Warnings:

```
9706 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
9900 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
```

and alot more of the same.

what do those errors mean?

I've read a few solutions already but non seemed to work for me,
any help on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.

FULL ERRORS:

```
9642 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\python\\env\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
9642 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
9829 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
9837 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\_lzma.pyd
9847 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
9863 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd
9879 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\select.pyd
9894 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\_socket.pyd
9910 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\_decimal.pyd
9926 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\_overlapped.pyd
9941 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
9948 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\_multiprocessing.pyd
9963 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
9979 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\_asyncio.pyd
10026 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
10026 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\_uuid.pyd
10042 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\_queue.pyd
10048 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_tests.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10079 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10095 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\lapack_lite.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10111 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\mtrand.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10111 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\_sfc64.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10126 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\_philox.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10126 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\_pcg64.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10142 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\_mt19937.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10148 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\bit_generator.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10164 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\_generator.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10180 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\_bounded_integers.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10180 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\_common.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10195 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\fft\_pocketfft_internal.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10211 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\_umath_linalg.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10227 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\pygame\imageext.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10227 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\pygame\fastevent.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10249 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\pygame\scrap.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10249 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\pygame\mixer.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10264 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\pygame\mixer_music.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10280 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\_elementtree.pyd
10296 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\pygame\font.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10311 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\pygame\_freetype.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10311 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\pygame\transform.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10327 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\pygame\time.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10343 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\pygame\pixelarray.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10353 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\pygame\mask.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10369 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\pygame\surface.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10369 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\pygame\pixelcopy.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10385 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\pygame\mouse.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10400 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\pygame\key.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10400 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\pygame\joystick.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10416 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\pygame\image.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10431 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\pygame\event.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10447 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\pygame\draw.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10449 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\pygame\display.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10465 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\pygame\math.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10480 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\pygame\bufferproxy.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10496 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\pygame\color.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10496 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\pygame\surflock.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10512 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\pygame\rwobject.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10522 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\pygame\rect.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10522 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\pygame\constants.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
10537 WARNING: lib not found: python39.dll dependency of c:\python\env\lib\site-packages\pygame\base.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the error using either `virtualenv` (to create a virtual environment) or python installation from python.org?

Comment: @gfdsweds I created a new virtualenv just like you said (and added the PATH), and it is working great,  Thank you ! :]